# Adding Model constraints using another Model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently  working on an application tracking app with Candidate, Application and Job models.

Ideally I would want a candidate to only apply once for a job, but the candidate should be able to apply to another Job if they wish.

The problem I am encountering is since the Application model is sitting in between the Candidate and Job, I am not sure where to add the constraint - where the Application model 'detects' whether the Candidate already exists in a Job or not through the defined relationships in the Application model.

Adding a unique constraint would only allow a Candidate to apply once throughout, so that would not be ideal.

- Candidate A -> Application A -> Job A  # should work
- Candidate A -> Application A -> Job A  # should throw error
- Candidate A -> Application B -> Job B  # should work

Here's my models.py

```
     class Candidate(models.Model):
            # Candidate Personal and Contact Information
            date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
            first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
            last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
            email = models.EmailField()
            phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)

        # Candidate Location Information
        city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        country = CountryField(blank_label='Select Country')
        zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'


class Application(models.Model):

    # Application Status Choices 
    class ApplicationStatus(models.TextChoices):
       ...


    # Application Stages Choices 
    class ApplicationStage(models.TextChoices):
       ...


    # Job-related Information
    date_applied = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    job = models.ForeignKey('Job', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    application_status = models.CharField(max_length=120,
                                          choices=ApplicationStatus.choices,
                                          default=ApplicationStatus.ACTIVE)
    stage = models.CharField(max_length=120,
                             choices=ApplicationStage.choices,
                             default=ApplicationStage.APPLICATION)

    # Applicant Information
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, 
                                  related_name='applications', 
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resume = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.job)


class Job(models.Model):

    # Job Status Choices
    class JobStatus(models.TextChoices):
        ...


    # Employment Type Choices
    class EmploymentType(models.TextChoices):
        ...

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    job_status = models.CharField(max_length=120,
                                  choices=JobStatus.choices,
                                  default=JobStatus.DRAFT)
    employment_type = models.CharField(max_length=120,
                                       choices=EmploymentType.choices,
                                       default=EmploymentType.FULL_TIME)
    compensation_min = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    compensation_max = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here's my serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rct.models import (Candidate,
                        Application,
                        InterviewSchedule,
                        Scorecard,
                        Job)


class CandidateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    applications = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta: 
        model = Candidate
        fields = '__all__'


class ApplicationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Application
        fields = '__all__'


class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta: 
        model = Job
        fields = '__all__'
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: "Adding a unique constraint would only allow a Candidate to apply once throughout" I didnét get this part but you should add unique together in Application model for fields Candidate and Job.

Comment: I feel so dumb having realized how simple it was. I added the unique_together constraint in the class Meta and it worked! THANK YOU.

Comment: It is great to hear that. I have posted an answer with my suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use unique_together index on `job` and `candidate` fields in `Application` model *Meta* class. To get more information, please visit official [model options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/) doc.